# How can I keep git repository only 1 commit history?

Tags: git

Look at the diagram:

[image]

How can I approach this?

If I use `pull`, all the commit histories will be pull down.

I don't want the git histories to consume my server's disk space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--depth`:

```
git clone --depth <remote>
```

See [`man git-clone`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html):

> `--depth <depth>`
>
> > Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions. A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if you are only interested in the recent history of a large project with a long history, and would want to send in fixes as patches.

I use this in exactly the case you describe, too, in fact, mostly for speed.

Comment: @CodinCat `git fetch --depth=1`

Comment: `pull` takes `--depth` as well, because it is `fetch` + `merge`. However, if you're only looking to use the contents of the repo, then no, you shouldn't need a merge commit. (Especially in a server that's just looking to run the code.) Just doing a `fetch` will probably be insufficient, as `fetch` doesn't touch the working dir. However, `git rebase` or `git reset` might be more appropriate than a `git merge`. (I would be very wary of running `git merge` in a deployment situation: a server should not create commits: it should be using a *particular* commit assigned to it.)

Comment: Using `git merge` is fine; in this case it'll result in a fast-forward update and never a merge commit.

Comment: @Magnus: I'm sure you know this, but if there has been a commit, it'll result in a merge commit. Now, I'm not saying there *should* be a commit, if it's a deployment in production, but I'd be a liar if I said I've never seen that happen. (Which is why a wrapper that *checks* if everything is sane first might be a better idea than any of `reset`/`merge`/`rebase` alone.)

Comment: Yes, fair point. Although, I'd argue that using Git for this type of deployment is a bad idea in the first place (for example because it assumes that what's in the git is exactly what you want to see deployed, a driver of pathological behavior).